# Async delegates casting/conversion

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, delegates, task

I have some class with property:

```
public class Test<TInput, TResult>
{
    public Func<Func<TInput, TResult>, Func<TInput, TResult>> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The `TResult` type can be any: `int`, `decimal`, `Task`, `Task<>`.

Let's say that `TResult` is `Task` or `Task<>` (just for this example). Please do not suggest to convert to `Func<TInput, Task<TResult>>` - this is not possible for my case.

Now I have some method (does not compile, see below):

```
public void MyMethod(Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, TResult> ifTrue)
{
    this.MyProperty = inputDelegate => async input =>
    {
        var predicateResult = await predicate.Invoke(input);

        return predicateResult ? await ifTrue.Invoke(input) : await inputDelegate.Invoke(input);
    };
}
```

Obviously there is compile time error saying that `async` cannot be used here because return type of this delegate should be `Task`-like or `void` (I know that `TResult` is `Task` or I can check, but compiler does not know).

I also tried with continuation:

```
public void MyMethod2(Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, TResult> ifTrue)
{
    this.MyProperty = inputDelegate => input =>
    {
        return predicate.Invoke(input)
            .ContinueWith(t => t.Result ? ifTrue.Invoke(input) : inputDelegate.Invoke(input));
    };
}
```

This method also does not compile as continuation result is not `TResult`, but `Task<TResult>`.

I guess there should be way to do this (I was playing with casting and delegates conversion, but I couldn't make it work).

Also keep in mind that it is not allowed to block on async, so just using `.Result` of `.Wait()` on task is not the case.

Having previous assumption about `TResult` is `Task`-like type is it possible to handle this situation somehow?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried to await inside continuation of `predicate`:

```
public void MyMethod3(Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, TResult> ifTrue)
{
    this.MyProperty = inputDelegate => input =>
    {
        var continuationTask = predicate.Invoke(input)
            .ContinueWith
            (
                async t =>
                {
                    var task = (Task)(object)(t.Result ? ifTrue.Invoke(input) : inputDelegate.Invoke(input));

                    await task;

                    object result = null;

                    var taskType = task.GetType();

                    if (taskType.IsGenericType) // Task<>
                    {
                        // task is already completed because of await above
                        result = taskType.GetProperty(nameof(Task<object>.Result)).GetValue(task);
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            ).Unwrap(); // make return type Task<object> from Task<Task<object>>

        // InvalidCastException -> if TResult is something different form Task<object>
        // if TResult is Task<int> then cast fails (because Task<int> and Task<object> are different types and task is not co/contra -variant)
        return (TResult)(object)continuationTask;
    };
}
```

But I can't cast final result to needed type.

Comment: simply don't mix async types with sync ones. bool, int and Task have absoluteley nothing in common, so there's little use in having a generic method that covers both, is it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `MyMethod` to be available on `Test<TInput, TResult>` objects, only when `TResult` is `Task` or `Task<T>`?

Comment: `await ifTrue.Invoke(input)` will not compile because `TResult` aren't Task-like type in `Func<TInput, TResult> ifTrue`. There is nothing in compile-time which would tell compiler that `TResult` is awaitable type.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, you're right, but I can't - to many changes to whole app. So I try to find other way (not the best one, I know)

Comment: @Sweeper, it would be good, but it won't solve the problem as at some time I need to get the result anyway (I'm using interface in real app).

Comment: @Fabio, it is possible if I cast to `Task` (see update), but then I have another issue with casting

Comment: `return predicateResult ? await ifTrue.Invoke(input) : await inputDelegate.Invoke(input);` But this method is supposed to return a `Func<TInput, TResult>`, not call one. Did you mean `return predicateResult ? ifTrue : inputDelegate;` ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman No, it's supposed to return a `TResult`. It's a nested lambda. It starts with `inputDelegate => async input => ...`

Comment: Ah, IMHO move the definition of `MyMethod` to another class with signature `Func<Func<TInput, Task<TResult>>,Func<TInput, Task<TResult>>> MyMethod<TInput, TResult>(Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, Task<TResult>> ifTrue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your problem is convincing the compiler that you are *sure* that `TResult` is `Task`/`Task<T>`.

If you use extension methods, you can write a `MyMethod` such that it only applies to `Test` objects where `TResult` is `Task`, and another overload that only applies to `Test` objects where `TResult` is `Task<T>`:

```
public static class TestExtensions {
    public static void MyMethod<TInput>(this Test<TInput, Task> test, Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, Task> ifTrue)
    {
        test.MyProperty = inputDelegate => async input =>
        {
            var predicateResult = await predicate.Invoke(input);

            if (predicateResult) {
                await ifTrue(input);
            } else {
                await inputDelegate(input);
            }
        };
    }
    public static void MyMethod<TInput, TResult>(this Test<TInput, Task<TResult>> test, Func<TInput, Task<bool>> predicate, Func<TInput, Task<TResult>> ifTrue)
    {
        test.MyProperty = inputDelegate => async input =>
        {
            var predicateResult = await predicate.Invoke(input);
            return predicateResult ? await ifTrue(input) : await inputDelegate(input);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Actually it even hides methods with async predicate when `TResult` is not `Task`. Thanks.